# "Parameters may not have the 'var' specifier" swift 3 compiler error

Tags: swift, swift3

I've been having this error when coding with inout parameters in swift 3.
The following code generates the error:

```
class Example {
var a : Int
    init(_ a: Int) {
        self.a=a
    }
}

let closure = { val in val.a = 7 } as (inout Example) -> ()
var v = Example(6)
closure(&v)
```

Console:

```
Playground execution failed: error: parameters may not have the 'var' specifier

* thread #1: tid = 0x12e365d, 0x00000001071d33c0 MyPlayground`executePlayground, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001071d33c0 MyPlayground`executePlayground
    frame #1: 0x00000001071d29c0 MyPlayground`__37-[XCPAppDelegate enqueueRunLoopBlock]_block_invoke + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000107cee6ac CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #3: 0x0000000107cd36f4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    frame #4: 0x0000000107cd2e65 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 901
    frame #5: 0x0000000107cd2884 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    frame #6: 0x000000010d172a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #7: 0x0000000108880c68 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #8: 0x00000001071d26e9 MyPlayground`main + 201
    frame #9: 0x000000010b2b468d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Is this code wrong? Where is this error coming from? Could it be a compiler bug?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an `inout` parameter here? You don't need to mutate the reference, only the underlying instance.

Comment: This is really really simplified version of what i have in my current project where i do have to use an inout parameter to configure an object via a closure. 
My intention should be independent of the error though

Comment: Are you sure you want a _type conversion_ (using `as`) from a closure to a given type? And not just simply annotate the type of the closure directly? `let closure: (inout Example) -> () = { val in val.a = 7 } ` compiles. None the less, the compiler error could be more telling; non-descriptive compiler messages may always be good to file a bug for.

Comment: Or `let closure = { (val: inout Example) in val.a = 7 }` :) Whether or not it's a compiler bug that it cannot infer the type with `as` is up for debate though – feel free to [file a bug on it anyway](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: This fixes the error, thank you very much

Comment: There seems to be a few bug reports where errors due to `inout` parameter usage (in different context) yields the off-point confusing error message _"parameters may not have the '`var`' specifier"_; e.g. [SR-2354](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2354) and [SR-3644](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3644). So might be worth filing a bug report that this misdiagnostic also shows when attempting to declare a closure as above (using `as`). Even if we should never want to use `as` in this declaring context, the additional `inout` to off-point error message might be valuable info for the Swift team.

Comment: @dfri I agree. The Swift team have specifically called out that they want to improve compiler error messages.

Comment: @dfri It's probably worth moving all that into an answer :)

Comment: @Hamish yes the comments did grow out of comment-proportion, thanks :) Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to avoid the error?

It seems you simply wants to declare a `()`-returning closure with a single `inout` parameter of a custom type. For this, there is no need to make use of type conversion (using `as`) to help the compiler infer the type of the closure.

You could (as pointed out by @Hamish) simply annotate the `inout` parameter type within the body of the closure, which suffices for the compiler to infer the closure type to `(inout Example) -> ()`:

```
let closure = { (val: inout Example) in val.a = 7 }
```

Or, you could explicitly type annotate the type of the closure:

```
let closure: (inout Example) -> () = { val in val.a = 7 }
```

---

#### An off-point misdiagnostic error -> consider filing a bug report

None the less, the compiler error in your example is a mis-diagnostic, which may be worth filing a bug for.

- https://bugs.swift.org/

There seems to already be a few bug reports where errors due to `inout` parameter usage (in different context) yields the off-point confusing error message "parameters may not have the '`var`' specifier"; e.g.

- [SR-2354: inout parameter in subscript gives the wrong error message](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2354)
- [SR-3644: Misleading diagnostics: parameters may not have the 'var' specifier](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3644)

Filing a bug report that this misdiagnostic also shows when attempting to declare a closure as above (using `as`) could be valuable info for the Swift team (additional `inout` to off-point error message cases), even if we should never want to use `as` in the declaring context of your example. As @matt writes in a comment.

> *"The Swift team have specifically called out that they want to improve compiler error messages."*